# Hide product price if 0 in magento 1.7?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm using magento 1.7.0.2 . In my store  I want to show some product which don't have price, and by default in magento they become 0.00 . There are some solution, for replacing:
this

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

with

```
<?php if($_product->price==0): ?> 
<?php echo 'Free'; /?> 
<?php else: ?> 
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And yes this is solve problem only if I replace in list.phtml (list and grid), but when I open product page with all details, there is still 0.00.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps you should try to do the same in view.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem, just need to replace this code, in path app\design\frontend\default\YOURTHEME\template\catalog\product:

```
 <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php if($_product->price==0): ?> 
<?php echo 'Free'; ?> 
<?php else: ?> 
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If i were right, u should not remove " <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?> " because it doesnt relate to the price. More over it relate to the error messages and notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-hide-price-extension

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, you're still sending all the controls to the client side, which could end up with users buying free products even though you've 'disabled' them.